# Put the current value of combobox or the html select box from DB

Tags: select, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I Have this code

```
{{Form::select('area_id', Area::lists('area_description','area_id') ,'',array('class' => 'form-control'))}
```

How do I get the current value of Select box from database. BTW I'm using Laravel with Blade Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have already solved my own problem wew.
with this code:

```
{{Form::select('area_id', $area_ids , $person->area_id ,array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
```

I forgot that it should be the id or the option value not the option content. The option that I mean is the `<option>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use something like this:

```php
{{
    Form::select(
        'area_id', 
        Area::lists('area_description','area_id'),
        old('area_id'), // or Input::old('area_id')
        ['class' => 'form-control']
    )
}}
```

In this case, instead of using `Area::lists('area_description','area_id')` inyour `template` use pass it from your controller, for example (in your controller):

```
$area_ids = Area::lists('area_description','area_id');

return view('view_name')->with('area_ids', $area_ids);
```

Then use the following in your `template`:

```
{{ Form::select('area_id', $area_ids, old('area_id'), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

### For Laravel-5.1.x

> The lists method now returns a Collection instance instead of a plain
>   array for Eloquent queries. If you would like to convert the
>   Collection into a plain array, use the all method:

```
$area_ids = Area::lists('area_description','area_id')->all();
```

Check [the upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0) for details.

Comment: it says Call to undefined function old()

Comment: What version? `old` is a helper function available since `5.0`

Comment: Alternatively you may use `Input::old('area_id')`